# Gradle Plugin/Task evaluated before build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

One of my plugins uses the files created by the gradle build of another project.
However gradle evaluates the plugin task before building. Is there a way to make the plugin tasks be created after the build is completed?

EDIT:

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'confluence-export'

sourceSets {
    tools
}

compileToolsJava {
    source += sourceSets.main.java
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    toolsCompile files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../lib/tools.jar")
}

task generateTagDoc(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.tools.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'TagsDocumentation'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}


task generateTypeDoc(type: Javadoc) {
    classpath = sourceSets.tools.runtimeClasspath
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.docletpath = compileToolsJava.outputs.files.asList()
    options.doclet = "ExtractCommentsDoclet"
    options.addStringOption("Tags.java")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
confluence {
    spaceKey = *****
    exportAll = true
    title = *******
    exportUser = "******
    exportPassword = ******
    libraryName = ******
    host = ********
}
asciidoctor {
    resources {
        from(sourceDir) {
            include 'img/**'
        }
    }
}

asciidoctor.dependsOn(generateTagDoc)
generateTagDoc.dependsOn(generateTypeDoc)
generateTypeDoc.dependsOn(compileToolsJava)
```

So here I want my build to run which will  create a folder asciidoc/html5 in the build folder with all my created html pages from my asciidoc files. My plugin goes through each file and creates a task for it and then uploads it to a website. The problem is the plugin task is evaluated before the build so the folder asciidoc/html5 hasn't been created yet. If i add a check to see if the folder has been created it will indeed remove my error however the task will still be empty. This is why i would like to know if there is a way for the plugin tasks to be created after the build is done so that the folder is created.

EDIT 2:
Here is the plugin creation:

```
class ConfluenceExportPlugin extends ConfluencePluginBase implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        def confluenceExtension = project.extensions.create('confluence', ConfluenceExtension)

        project.afterEvaluate {
            if (confluenceExtension.exportAll) {
                def list = []
                def dir = new File("${project.buildDir}/asciidoc/html5")
                if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
                dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
                    if(it.name.endsWith('.html')) {
                        list.add(it)
                    }
                }

                Task mainTask = project.task('confluenceExport')
                mainTask.dependsOn("build")
                list.each { file ->
                    def curName = file.name.take(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'))
                    ConfluenceExportTask subTask = createTask(project, "confluenceExport${curName}", confluenceExtension, file.path, curName)
                    mainTask.dependsOn(subTask)
                }
            }
            else {
                ConfluenceExportTask task = createTask(project, "confluenceExport", confluenceExtension, getManFile(confluenceExtension, project), confluenceExtension.title)
            }
        }

    }

    ConfluenceExportTask createTask(Project project, String taskName, def confluenceExtension, manFile, String pageTitle ){
        ConfluenceExportTask task = project.task(type: ConfluenceExportTask, taskName)
        task.conventionMapping.map "user", { confluenceExtension.user }
        task.conventionMapping.map "password", { confluenceExtension.password }
        task.conventionMapping.map "spaceKey", { confluenceExtension.spaceKey }
        task.conventionMapping.map "manFile", { manFile }
        task.conventionMapping.map "pageTitle", { pageTitle }
        task
    }

    String getManFile(ConfluenceExtension configuration, Project project) {
        configuration.exportSourceFilePath ?: "${project.buildDir}/asciidoc/html5/${configuration.libraryName}.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could please elaborate on the problem it will be easier to help. Maybe an example?

Comment: I edited my question for you :)

Comment: How is your plugin implemented right now?

Comment: I added the plugin creation too

Comment: Ok, so the simple answer is to move the logic to the tasks action. Then it will pick the folder on execution time. The second option is configure a `TaskInput` where you'll set the directory name only and it will be processed on execution time. You can combine both solutions.

Comment: I mean logic in `project.afterEvaluate` to be precise. More or less you need to move it to actions.